# GetOpenFilename opens Dialogue box behind PowerPoint Presentation

Tags: excel, powerpoint

I'm using VBA in powerPoint to update links to Excel Objects in my PowerPoint and everything is working well. The only Issue I have is that sometimes the Select File dialogue box opens behind the active Powerpoint and the only way to select it is to CTRL+ALT+Del and select the Excel File Chooser and set it as active. Is there a way to make it always be the active dialogue box when it opens? Here's the code I'm using:

```
Sub UpdateLinks()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim sh As Shape
Dim strNms As String
Dim intI As Integer
Dim strNewPath
Dim ExcelFile
Dim exl As Object
Set exl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'Set exl = exl.ActiveWindow
'exl.Active = True
 'Open a dialog box to promt for the new source file.
ExcelFile = exl.Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Select Excel File")
'Go through every slide
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each sh In sld.Shapes
        If sh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
            With sh.LinkFormat
                strNms = .SourceFullName
                intI = InStr(1, strNms, "!")
                strNewPath = ExcelFile & Mid(strNms, intI, Len(strNms) - intI + 1)
                .SourceFullName = strNewPath
            End With
        End If
    Next sh
Next sld
ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks
```

End Sub

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you're running this from within PPT, is there some reason why you're not invoking the PPT app's file chooser dialog instead of doing it through Excel?

Comment: I guess the only reason is because that is the portion of code someone else had posted for how to update msoLinkedOLEObjects. I'm not sure how to do that using PPT's file chooser.

Comment: Try making the Excel application visible before calling the GetOpenFilename method.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:  try this version of a file picker instead:

```
Sub FileDialogExample()
' Courtesy of John Wilson
' www.pptalchemy.co.uk

    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim sFilename As String

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls, *.xlsx"
        .InitialFileName = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = True Then sFilename = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    'do whatever with sFilename
    MsgBox "You picked " & sFilename

End Sub
```